# why does println("\n") do not work in scala

Tags: scala

Hi so I have a code here:

```
var ckList = ["a", "b", "c"]
for {
  ck <- ckList
} {
  println(s"${ck} \n")
}
```

I want it to be printed like this:

```
a

b

c
```

not like this:

```
a
b
c
```

Please help

Comment: I tried on Scala Repl, it is working as you expected.

Comment: in https://scalafiddle.io it does NOT work: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/CMUJmu8/0

Comment: @pme Scala Fiddle is removing blank lines from the output which is why it appears not to work correctly.

Comment: @Tim thanks, I did not know that. Strangely `\n\n` gives you one blank line. `print` does not print at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix the code and run it as an application it works as expected.

```
object TestApp extends App {
  val ckList = List("a", "b", "c")

  for {
    ck <- ckList
  } {
    println(s"$ck \n")
  }
}
```

If you are using Scala Fiddle it will remove blank lines from the output, but they are still being generated by the code.